# What is the responseXML in an ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

This is a piece of code that I am working on, however there are some issues that I do not understand:

```
handleGeocoderResponse: function(response, ajaxOptions, comboBoxIdentifier) {
    var self = this;
    var xml = response.responseXML ;

    // step 1: error process explicit error message, then exit out of here if we encounter an error
    var errorNode = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode("error", xml);
    if (errorNode) {
        console.log("GEOCODE ERROR: " + errorNode.firstChild.nodeValue);
        this.form.setErrorMessage(comboBoxIdentifier);
        return;
    }
```

the function `handleGeocoderResponse` represents the success function in an 
ext.ajax.request, what I don't understand is the var xml. What is responseXML and what exactly should return it? and what about (Ext.DomQuery.selectNode) and what its supposed to do ?

Answer (score 3):

The `.responseXML` property of the `response` object given to an `XMLHttpRequest`'s `success` method is a `Document` object representing the XML which was returned from the server after it has been parsed (if parseable XML was returned).

`.selectNode` is a method of `Ext`'s `DomQuery` module which allows you to ask for DOM elements from a given Document or DOM node. In this case, it is asking for the `error` node of the Document returned from the server during the request.

- Mozilla's `XMLHttpRequest` `responseXML` docs:

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#responseXML
- Ext `DomQuery` `selectNode` docs:

  - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery-method-selectNode